# How can I add a batch file to visual basic and execute by pressing a button?

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, visual-studio-2013

I created a visual basic windows form application using Visual Studio 2013.
I create a text file in add new item and rename it to run.bat.
and write my codes on it.
And also created a button.
My question is how can i execute the batch file when i click the button?
I tried this code but doesn't work.

```
Process.Start("run.bat")
```

[image]

please view the image.
i want to execute the batch file under form1.vb

Comment: @Ken White I know how to run a batch file which is in local machine. i want to know how can i run the batch file if the file is in within the form application.

Comment: @MaxySpark what do you mean "within the form application"? It doesn't make sence, a batch file should be on the hard drive to be able to run it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *batch file within the form application*. A batch file is a file that is on the disk (which is why it's called a **file**), that is run using `cmd.exe`. Your question makes no sense. If you need to do something in your form application, use VB code to do it. If you need something that can only run from a batch file under `cmd.exe`, write out the batch file to disk and execute it using `Process.Start`.

Comment: Elaborate on "It doesn't work".

Comment: @Steve: Read the comments.

Comment: please view the image.
i want to execute the batch file under form1.vb

Comment: I assume, 'It doesn't work" means you get an error "File not found" when you run it. Click on the file in your solution and in your properties window, change "Build Action" to "Content" and the "Copy to output directory" to "Always". Run and try again.

Comment: @Steve thanx it works. I set Copy to output directory" to "Always"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you add a general file to your project, it will be compiled into the EXE/DLL as an embedded resource and there are ways to get at that. But in your case, you want a copy of the file in the executable's directory so you can run it.

Two setting you need to work with are:

**Build Action** - The default is NONE (for a bat file) which means it is ignored during the build. You want to change this to CONTENT so when you create your install package, it will be seen as a file that the installer will package and put in the end users executable folder.

**Copy to output folder** - This is basically used for development so VS knows what to do with the file, it has nothing to do with the install package. By default this is NEVER which means that VS does nothing with it. You want this to be ALWAYS so it will make a copy of this file into the same folder your EXE is in.